# I can not get development license for windows 8.1 error 0x8024500C

Tags: visual-studio-2015, windows-8.1

The OS of my computer is Windows 8.1 Pro and my IDE is VS2015 Professional. My computer has network connectivity  My Windows is updated, I executed VS with Admin privileges, also I opened power Shell to execute Show-WindowsDeveloperLicenseRegistration. Altough all of this, the development license is not installed. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The error `0x8024500C` means `WU_E_REDIRECTOR_CONNECT_POLICY - Connections to the redirector server are disallowed by managed policy.` So you have applied some Windows Update group policies which prevent the connection to the MS page to get the license.

Comment: So, do I need modify my group policies?

Comment: yeah, look which one are applied to your device and change them

Comment: I did it but the problem was not solved. So, I installed win 10 and the development license for vs2015 already works very well